# Is there a way in Swift to get an associated value without using a switch statement?

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement, let, associated-value

When I have a situation where I already know enum case statement I want to get the associated value of, is there a cleaner way than using a switch statement to pluck out the associated value?

To have to come up with a switch statement, provide multiple cases, or a default case just to extract the associated value is gaudy.

```
enum CircularReasoning {
    case justPi(pi: Double)
    case pizzaPie(howMany: Int)
}

var piInTheSky : Double 

let whatLogic = CircularReasoning(pi: 3.1415926)

⬇️    ⬇️ 

switch whatLogic {
    case .justPi(let pi):
        piInTheSky = pi!
    default:
        break
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `if case .<enum_case>(let value)` as in TylerP's example,
or `if case let .<enum_case>(value)`:

```
enum Foo {
    case anInt(Int)
    case aFloat(Float)
}

let aFoo: Foo = .anInt(9)

// Example of `if case .<enum_case)(let value)` syntax:
if case .anInt(let aValue) = aFoo {
    print("aFoo = anInt(\(aValue))")

// Example of `if case let .enum_case(value)` syntax:
} else if case let .aFloat(aValue) = aFoo {
    print("aFoo = aFloat(\(aValue))")
}
```

Both work. I'm not sure why the language includes both variants.

If you only care about one enum type, then either `if` syntax makes sense to me. If you are dealing with more than one possible enum value then the switch version seems cleaner.

Comment: I totally agree switch is cleaner for multiples, but in my case the way I'm setting up a parser, I have many cases where I would only have a switch with one case statement to extract one associated value set, in lieu of your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an adaptation of @DuncanC's excellent upvoted and accepted answer, as applied to a fictitious version of my real-world use case.

It illustrates a possible way to use his answer to reduce the space required to extract associated values, especially if one has a lot of one-off cases...

*Note: Not implying this is appropriate or professional swift styling; it's clearly idiosyncratic, yet compact. (I usually don't compress things into one liners like this, unless they get really repetitive/redundant & produce lot of pointless vertical bloat).*

```
enum RealmKey { case realmOfRealms, anyOldRealm, someOtherRealm }
.
.
.
enum SymbolToken {
    case realm       (key: RealmKey?)
    case space       (key: SpaceKey?)
    case area        (key: AreaKey?)
    case region      (key: RegionKey?)
    case preserve    (key: PeserveKey?)
    case openParen
    case closeParen
    case logicalAnd
    case logicalOr
    case logicalNot
    
    var realmKey    : RealmKey?    { if case .realm    (let key) = self { return key } else { return nil } }
    var spaceKey    : SpaceKey?    { if case .space    (let key) = self { return key } else { return nil } }
    var areaKey     : AreaKey?     { if case .area     (let key) = self { return key } else { return nil } }
    var regionKey   : RegionKey?   { if case .region   (let key) = self { return key } else { return nil } }
    var preserveKey : PreserveKey? { if case .preserve (let key) = self { return key } else { return nil } }
}

let realm = SymbolToken.realm(.realmOfRealms)
let realmKey = realm.realmKey
```